# Azure Data Lake Store - error while reading from file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I use [FileSystemOperationsExtensions.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.filesystemoperationsextensions.open?view=azuremgmtdatalakestore-2.1.0-preview#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_FileSystemOperationsExtensions_Open_Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_IFileSystemOperations_System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int64__System_Nullable_System_Int64__) method that returns Stream and I can read from it.
Sometimes when service is reading big files from the stream (~150-300 Mb) service gets the following exceptions:

```
System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

"ClassName": "System.IO.IOException",
"Message": "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
 at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n   
 at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

And it occurs randomly.
Also, I create an object of [DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.datalakestorefilesystemmanagementclient.-ctor?view=azuremgmtdatalakestore-2.1.0-preview#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataLake_Store_DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient__ctor_Microsoft_Rest_ServiceClientCredentials_System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_System_Net_Http_DelegatingHandler___)  class with 60 minutes timeout, but these errors occur before it.
It may take 3, 10, 20 or whatever minutes.
Of course, I can reread stream with offset, but it requires extra time for development.
Perhaps there is another way to avoid these exceptions.
Could anybody help me with it?

Comment: Answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400730/azure-data-lake-store-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-ho

Answer (score 1):

I do a demo test with 270M+ size file 3 times, it always works correctly for me. Please have a try to using the following code to test it. We also can get more datalake store demo code from [data lake store get started net sdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk.md).

[image]

Demo code:

```
var applicationId = "Application Id";
                var secretKey = "secretkey";
                var tenantId = "tenant id";
                var adlsAccountName = "Account name";
                var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;
                var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds,clientTimeoutInMinutes:60);
                var srcPath = "/mytempdir/ForDemoCode.zip";
                var destPath = @"c:\tom\ForDemoCode1.zip";

                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();
                using (var stream = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(adlsAccountName, srcPath))
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
                var file = new FileInfo(destPath);
                Console.WriteLine($"File size :{file.Length}");
                stopWatch.Stop();
                // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
                string elapsedTime = $"{ts.Hours:00}:{ts.Minutes:00}:{ts.Seconds:00}.{ts.Milliseconds/10:00}";
                Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
                Console.ReadKey();
```

package config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store" version="2.1.1-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader" version="1.0.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.13.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.2-beta1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: ,What is the namespace for **ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync**.
I was got this following error.
 **"The name 'ApplicationTokenProvider' does not exist in the current context"**

Comment: In the `Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication` namespace, I also mentioned it in the packages.config file section. Please reference the following .dll file `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication`